# What is going on with chromes handling of sessions/cookies compared to safari and firefox

Tags: php, session, google-chrome, browser, safari

On chrome I am experiencing the following issue:

- Login with username and password which creates a cookie for the username and a login sesion.
- view main page (which has a script to check for login session)
- logout
- Attempt to view main page.  But am booted back to login screen/home.
- Refresh and attempt to view main page.  Booted back to login screen.
- Browse to any other site.
- Return to `example.com/mainpage.php` and I am now able to view it (with the previous username)

The problem is that obviously when returning to the site, the user should still be logged out and unable to view mainpage.php until they log in.

I am VERY bewildered by this.  On a whim I checked how this was being processed on other browsers. And the problem does not occur on Safari, Firefox or IE.  They properly kick the user back to the home page.

It seems as though chrome is "suspending" the session instead of properly ending it and then is reenacting the session when I navigate back to the site.

The relevant script is as follows:

```
// log out script
session_start();
setcookie("username", "", time()-360000);
setcookie("token", "", time()-360000);
$_SESSION["Login"] = "no";


// The mainpage script
if ($_SESSION["Login"] != "YES")
  header("location: home.php");
```

Comment: Did you check if chrome is showing a cached page?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use: `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` to close the session?

Comment: I could, and did.  I changed to this system in a recent attempt to trouble shoot. The problem was occurring identically with the more normal session destruction method.

Comment: hmmm odd, try adding a `var_dump` of the session variables at the top of the mainpage, and see what it outputs when you return to the page after logging out

Comment: Thank you for the reformat.  Sorry for being sloppy.

Comment: @Stu the result of the var_dump is:

string(3) "YES"

I am not sure what the (3) means. Im not experienced with var_dump.

but i'm SO SO SO confused why it would be still set to "YES"

Comment: have you tried using `$_COOKIE` instead of `$_SESSION`? Shot in the dark, but might give you different results?

Comment: have you tried on a separate machine with no extensions installed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Figured I would document it here for anyone who is still puzzled.

Somehow (beyond me) the wildcard redirect was not condensing www. and non www. visits to the site into the same (I used www. for all).

As a result for some reason, some pages were processing with a dub dub dub and others werent.  This was especially the case when leaving the site and revisiting... the logout killed the session in the www version but then returned to the non-dubbed version and was like "oh still logged in"